# Change String To Some Fix Format Using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Let Suppos I have String

```
<td> <?=$row['password']?> </td>
```

Which Returns

```
<td>123</td>
```

Now I Wants to Hide This As

```
<td>***</td>
```

For sollution i tried to put it in input type password. so i wants to ask that is there **any Sollution Using JQUERY**.

I Do not want to hide or show i just want to change it to fix format. for example if i use $ instead of * so all string will changes to $.

I also look for `str_replace()`. but it does not make sense.

Comment: You can store the original text as attribute and set text of element as ***

Comment: you should not show password in your view.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: I do not wants to show password as it is. i wanted to show after changing its format @Badiparmagi

Comment: if you are not going to use it put some random chars.

Comment: Why use `jQuery`? Print `***` on PHP

Comment: Means i wants to change String to *** or #### is it possible without jquery ? it doesn't mater jquery or php. just need o/p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not advisable** to use `jQuery` to mask your password. This is how to do it using `PHP`

```
$password = "1234567890";
$password = str_repeat("*", strlen($password)); 

echo '<td>' . $password . '</td>';
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `css`.

```js
console.log($('.disc').text());
```

```css
.disc {
  font-family: "text-security-disc";
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='disc'>123</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: its Quite good solution but what if i need * or # instead of text-security-disc?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JQuery, in PHP, you can use [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

```
<td><?=str_repeat("*", strlen($row['password']));?></td>
```